# Place many TikZ drawings in one page

Tags: tikz-pgf, floats

I've some problems with aligning many drawings I made with TikZ: I want these TikZ pictured below to be displayed like in example:

[image]

But finally my pictures aranged with blank space:

[image]

How can I fix this issue.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usepackage[europeanresistors]{circuitikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{caption}

 \usepackage{amsmath}
 \usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
 \usetikzlibrary{patterns}
  \usepackage{mathrsfs}
 \newcommand{\EDS}{\ensuremath{\mathscr{E}}}
 \usepackage{enumitem}
 
\usetikzlibrary{datavisualization}

%Image-related packages
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}




\begin{document}



\begin{figure}[h]
    \halign{\hfil#\hfil&\hfil#\hfil&\hfil#\hfil\cr
    \parbox[b]{0.33\textwidth}{\centerline{ 


\begin{circuitikz}[european]

    \newcommand{\potol}[3]{\pgfmathsetmacro{\x}{#1}\pgfmathsetmacro{\y}{#2}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\L}{#3}
    \draw[thick] (\x,\y) -- ++(\L,0); \draw (\x,\y+0.1) -- ++(0.1,0.1);
    \foreach \p in {0.2,0.3,...,\L} \draw ({\x+\p-0.2},\y) -- ++(0.2,0.2); \draw ({\x+\L-0.2},\y) -- ++(0.2,0.2);
    \draw ({\x+\L-0.1},\y) -- ++(0.1,0.1);}
      \potol{-0.5}{2.5}{1};
      \draw (0,2.5) -- (0,0);
      \filldraw[draw=black,fill=lightgray] (0,0) circle (.4);


\end{circuitikz}}\vspace{-0.2cm}\caption{}\label{}}
&\parbox[b]{0.33\textwidth}{\centerline{ 


\begin{circuitikz}[european]
    
    \newcommand{\potol}[3]{\pgfmathsetmacro{\x}{#1}\pgfmathsetmacro{\y}{#2}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\L}{#3}
    \draw[thick] (\x,\y) -- ++(\L,0); \draw (\x,\y+0.1) -- ++(0.1,0.1);
    \foreach \p in {0.2,0.3,...,\L} \draw ({\x+\p-0.2},\y) -- ++(0.2,0.2); \draw ({\x+\L-0.2},\y) -- ++(0.2,0.2);
    \draw ({\x+\L-0.1},\y) -- ++(0.1,0.1);}
      \potol{-0.5}{2.5}{1};
      \draw (0,2.5) -- (0,0);
      \filldraw[draw=black,fill=lightgray] (0,0) circle (.4);


      
    

\end{circuitikz}}\vspace{-0.2cm}\caption{}\label{}}
 &\parbox[b]{0.33\textwidth}{\centerline{ 
 
 \begin{circuitikz}[european]
 \newcommand{\potol}[3]{\pgfmathsetmacro{\x}{#1}\pgfmathsetmacro{\y}{#2}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\L}{#3}
    \draw[thick] (\x,\y) -- ++(\L,0); \draw (\x,\y+0.1) -- ++(0.1,0.1);
    \foreach \p in {0.2,0.3,...,\L} \draw ({\x+\p-0.2},\y) -- ++(0.2,0.2); \draw ({\x+\L-0.2},\y) -- ++(0.2,0.2);
    \draw ({\x+\L-0.1},\y) -- ++(0.1,0.1);}
      \potol{-0.5}{2.5}{1};
      \draw (0,2.5) -- (0,0);
      \filldraw[draw=black,fill=lightgray] (0,0) circle (.4);
    
   
    
\end{circuitikz}}\vspace{-0.2cm}\caption{}\label{}}\cr}
\end{figure}


\begin{figure}[h]
    \halign{\hfil#\hfil&\hfil#\hfil&\hfil#\hfil\cr
    \parbox[b]{0.33\textwidth}{\centerline{ 


\begin{circuitikz}[european]

     \newcommand{\potol}[3]{\pgfmathsetmacro{\x}{#1}\pgfmathsetmacro{\y}{#2}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\L}{#3}
    \draw[thick] (\x,\y) -- ++(\L,0); \draw (\x,\y+0.1) -- ++(0.1,0.1);
    \foreach \p in {0.2,0.3,...,\L} \draw ({\x+\p-0.2},\y) -- ++(0.2,0.2); \draw ({\x+\L-0.2},\y) -- ++(0.2,0.2);
    \draw ({\x+\L-0.1},\y) -- ++(0.1,0.1);}
      \potol{-0.5}{2.5}{1};
      \draw (0,2.5) -- (0,0);
      \filldraw[draw=black,fill=lightgray] (0,0) circle (.4);


\end{circuitikz}}\vspace{-0.2cm}\caption{}\label{}}
&\parbox[b]{0.33\textwidth}{\centerline{ 


\begin{circuitikz}[european]
    
      \newcommand{\potol}[3]{\pgfmathsetmacro{\x}{#1}\pgfmathsetmacro{\y}{#2}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\L}{#3}
    \draw[thick] (\x,\y) -- ++(\L,0); \draw (\x,\y+0.1) -- ++(0.1,0.1);
    \foreach \p in {0.2,0.3,...,\L} \draw ({\x+\p-0.2},\y) -- ++(0.2,0.2); \draw ({\x+\L-0.2},\y) -- ++(0.2,0.2);
    \draw ({\x+\L-0.1},\y) -- ++(0.1,0.1);}
      \potol{-0.5}{2.5}{1};
      \draw (0,2.5) -- (0,0);
      \filldraw[draw=black,fill=lightgray] (0,0) circle (.4);

      
    

\end{circuitikz}}\vspace{-0.2cm}\caption{}\label{}}
 &\parbox[b]{0.33\textwidth}{\centerline{ 
 
 \begin{circuitikz}[european]
 
         \newcommand{\potol}[3]{\pgfmathsetmacro{\x}{#1}\pgfmathsetmacro{\y}{#2}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\L}{#3}
    \draw[thick] (\x,\y) -- ++(\L,0); \draw (\x,\y+0.1) -- ++(0.1,0.1);
    \foreach \p in {0.2,0.3,...,\L} \draw ({\x+\p-0.2},\y) -- ++(0.2,0.2); \draw ({\x+\L-0.2},\y) -- ++(0.2,0.2);
    \draw ({\x+\L-0.1},\y) -- ++(0.1,0.1);}
      \potol{-0.5}{2.5}{1};
      \draw (0,2.5) -- (0,0);
      \filldraw[draw=black,fill=lightgray] (0,0) circle (.4);
    
   
    
\end{circuitikz}}\vspace{-0.2cm}\caption{}\label{}}\cr}
\end{figure}


\begin{figure}[h]
    \halign{\hfil#\hfil&\hfil#\hfil&\hfil#\hfil\cr
    \parbox[b]{0.33\textwidth}{\centerline{ 


\begin{circuitikz}[european]

    \newcommand{\potol}[3]{\pgfmathsetmacro{\x}{#1}\pgfmathsetmacro{\y}{#2}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\L}{#3}
    \draw[thick] (\x,\y) -- ++(\L,0); \draw (\x,\y+0.1) -- ++(0.1,0.1);
    \foreach \p in {0.2,0.3,...,\L} \draw ({\x+\p-0.2},\y) -- ++(0.2,0.2); \draw ({\x+\L-0.2},\y) -- ++(0.2,0.2);
    \draw ({\x+\L-0.1},\y) -- ++(0.1,0.1);}
      \potol{-0.5}{2.5}{1};
      \draw (0,2.5) -- (0,0);
      \filldraw[draw=black,fill=lightgray] (0,0) circle (.4);


\end{circuitikz}}\vspace{-0.2cm}\caption{}\label{}}
&\parbox[b]{0.33\textwidth}{\centerline{ 


\begin{circuitikz}[european]
    
        \newcommand{\potol}[3]{\pgfmathsetmacro{\x}{#1}\pgfmathsetmacro{\y}{#2}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\L}{#3}
    \draw[thick] (\x,\y) -- ++(\L,0); \draw (\x,\y+0.1) -- ++(0.1,0.1);
    \foreach \p in {0.2,0.3,...,\L} \draw ({\x+\p-0.2},\y) -- ++(0.2,0.2); \draw ({\x+\L-0.2},\y) -- ++(0.2,0.2);
    \draw ({\x+\L-0.1},\y) -- ++(0.1,0.1);}
      \potol{-0.5}{2.5}{1};
      \draw (0,2.5) -- (0,0);
      \filldraw[draw=black,fill=lightgray] (0,0) circle (.4);


      
    

\end{circuitikz}}\vspace{-0.2cm}\caption{}\label{}}
 &\parbox[b]{0.33\textwidth}{\centerline{ 
 
 \begin{circuitikz}[european]
 
        \newcommand{\potol}[3]{\pgfmathsetmacro{\x}{#1}\pgfmathsetmacro{\y}{#2}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\L}{#3}
    \draw[thick] (\x,\y) -- ++(\L,0); \draw (\x,\y+0.1) -- ++(0.1,0.1);
    \foreach \p in {0.2,0.3,...,\L} \draw ({\x+\p-0.2},\y) -- ++(0.2,0.2); \draw ({\x+\L-0.2},\y) -- ++(0.2,0.2);
    \draw ({\x+\L-0.1},\y) -- ++(0.1,0.1);}
      \potol{-0.5}{2.5}{1};
      \draw (0,2.5) -- (0,0);
      \filldraw[draw=black,fill=lightgray] (0,0) circle (.4);
    
   
    
\end{circuitikz}}\vspace{-0.2cm}\caption{}\label{}}\cr}
\end{figure}


\begin{figure}[h]
    \halign{\hfil#\hfil&\hfil#\hfil&\hfil#\hfil\cr
    \parbox[b]{0.33\textwidth}{\centerline{ 


\begin{circuitikz}[european]

        \newcommand{\potol}[3]{\pgfmathsetmacro{\x}{#1}\pgfmathsetmacro{\y}{#2}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\L}{#3}
    \draw[thick] (\x,\y) -- ++(\L,0); \draw (\x,\y+0.1) -- ++(0.1,0.1);
    \foreach \p in {0.2,0.3,...,\L} \draw ({\x+\p-0.2},\y) -- ++(0.2,0.2); \draw ({\x+\L-0.2},\y) -- ++(0.2,0.2);
    \draw ({\x+\L-0.1},\y) -- ++(0.1,0.1);}
      \potol{-0.5}{2.5}{1};
      \draw (0,2.5) -- (0,0);
      \filldraw[draw=black,fill=lightgray] (0,0) circle (.4);



\end{circuitikz}}\vspace{-0.2cm}\caption{}\label{}}
&\parbox[b]{0.33\textwidth}{\centerline{ 


\begin{circuitikz}[european]
    
        \newcommand{\potol}[3]{\pgfmathsetmacro{\x}{#1}\pgfmathsetmacro{\y}{#2}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\L}{#3}
    \draw[thick] (\x,\y) -- ++(\L,0); \draw (\x,\y+0.1) -- ++(0.1,0.1);
    \foreach \p in {0.2,0.3,...,\L} \draw ({\x+\p-0.2},\y) -- ++(0.2,0.2); \draw ({\x+\L-0.2},\y) -- ++(0.2,0.2);
    \draw ({\x+\L-0.1},\y) -- ++(0.1,0.1);}
      \potol{-0.5}{2.5}{1};
      \draw (0,2.5) -- (0,0);
      \filldraw[draw=black,fill=lightgray] (0,0) circle (.4);

      
    



  \end{circuitikz}}\vspace{-0.2cm}\caption{}\label{}}
     &\parbox[b]{0.33\textwidth}{\centerline{ 
 
 \begin{circuitikz}[european]
 
         \newcommand{\potol}[3]{\pgfmathsetmacro{\x}{#1}\pgfmathsetmacro{\y}{#2}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\L}{#3}
    \draw[thick] (\x,\y) -- ++(\L,0); \draw (\x,\y+0.1) -- ++(0.1,0.1);
    \foreach \p in {0.2,0.3,...,\L} \draw ({\x+\p-0.2},\y) -- ++(0.2,0.2); \draw ({\x+\L-0.2},\y) -- ++(0.2,0.2);
    \draw ({\x+\L-0.1},\y) -- ++(0.1,0.1);}
      \potol{-0.5}{2.5}{1};
      \draw (0,2.5) -- (0,0);
      \filldraw[draw=black,fill=lightgray] (0,0) circle (.4);
    
   
    
\end{circuitikz}}\vspace{-0.2cm}\caption{}\label{}}\cr}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[h]
    \halign{\hfil#\hfil&\hfil#\hfil&\hfil#\hfil\cr
    \parbox[b]{0.33\textwidth}{\centerline{ 


\begin{circuitikz}[european]

        \newcommand{\potol}[3]{\pgfmathsetmacro{\x}{#1}\pgfmathsetmacro{\y}{#2}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\L}{#3}
    \draw[thick] (\x,\y) -- ++(\L,0); \draw (\x,\y+0.1) -- ++(0.1,0.1);
    \foreach \p in {0.2,0.3,...,\L} \draw ({\x+\p-0.2},\y) -- ++(0.2,0.2); \draw ({\x+\L-0.2},\y) -- ++(0.2,0.2);
    \draw ({\x+\L-0.1},\y) -- ++(0.1,0.1);}
      \potol{-0.5}{2.5}{1};
      \draw (0,2.5) -- (0,0);
      \filldraw[draw=black,fill=lightgray] (0,0) circle (.4);




  \end{circuitikz}}\vspace{-0.2cm}\caption{}\label{}}
    &\parbox[b]{0.33\textwidth}{\centerline{ 


\begin{circuitikz}[european]
    
      \newcommand{\potol}[3]{\pgfmathsetmacro{\x}{#1}\pgfmathsetmacro{\y}{#2}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\L}{#3}
    \draw[thick] (\x,\y) -- ++(\L,0); \draw (\x,\y+0.1) -- ++(0.1,0.1);
    \foreach \p in {0.2,0.3,...,\L} \draw ({\x+\p-0.2},\y) -- ++(0.2,0.2); \draw ({\x+\L-0.2},\y) -- ++(0.2,0.2);
    \draw ({\x+\L-0.1},\y) -- ++(0.1,0.1);}
      \potol{-0.5}{2.5}{1};
      \draw (0,2.5) -- (0,0);
      \filldraw[draw=black,fill=lightgray] (0,0) circle (.4);



 \end{circuitikz}}\vspace{-0.2cm}\caption{}\label{}}
     &\parbox[b]{0.33\textwidth}{\centerline{ 
 
 \begin{circuitikz}[european]
 
         \newcommand{\potol}[3]{\pgfmathsetmacro{\x}{#1}\pgfmathsetmacro{\y}{#2}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\L}{#3}
    \draw[thick] (\x,\y) -- ++(\L,0); \draw (\x,\y+0.1) -- ++(0.1,0.1);
    \foreach \p in {0.2,0.3,...,\L} \draw ({\x+\p-0.2},\y) -- ++(0.2,0.2); \draw ({\x+\L-0.2},\y) -- ++(0.2,0.2);
    \draw ({\x+\L-0.1},\y) -- ++(0.1,0.1);}
      \potol{-0.5}{2.5}{1};
      \draw (0,2.5) -- (0,0);
      \filldraw[draw=black,fill=lightgray] (0,0) circle (.4);
    
   
    
\end{circuitikz}}\vspace{-0.2cm}\caption{}\label{}}\cr}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You should be using `[htbp!]` float specifier instead of `[h]`. Giving only `h` is not a best way to make float placements.

Comment: If they shouldn't float, don't use figure at all!

Comment: Also the given images do not match the given MWE exactly.

Answer (score 3):

If you do not need to float things, do not use `figure`: simply put the picture where you need them. A `tikzpicture` is just a box for LaTeX, exactly the same as a letter.

Your MWE is not Minimal at all, so I made another one. I define two commands for two pictures, just as example, and define where they "baselines" are --- they will be aligned at that level. Then I use the `use as a bounding box` to make the picture a fixed size so that they will stack nicely vertically.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand{\drawingA}{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(A.base)]
        % set a fixed size for the picture
        \path[use as bounding box] (-2,-2) rectangle (2,2);
        \draw[thick] node[draw, circle, fill=yellow](A) {A} (A.south) -- ++(0,-1);
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}
\newcommand{\drawingB}{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(A.base)]
        % set a fixed size for the picture
        \path[use as bounding box] (-2,-2) rectangle (2,2);
        \draw[thick] (0,0) node[draw, rectangle, fill=cyan](B) {B}
            (B.south) ++(-1,0) -- ++(2,0);
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}
\parindent=0pt
\begin{document}
    \drawingA \drawingA \drawingB \par
    \drawingB \drawingA \drawingB \par
\end{document}
```

[image]